# Nested Calculated Column Returns Invalid Syntax

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula

I have a column `[Meeting Date]` which is used to determine `[Initial Date]`. The user when creating a new list item, inserts a date for [Meeting Date] which is automatically set to Today's date. [Initial Date] is set to `[Meeting Date] + 2` but notice the following formula I used the WEEKDAY formula with the (2) return type to see if the value is a Thursday or Friday to calculate for the weekend/only business days:

```
[Initial Date] Formula
=IF(
    WEEKDAY(
        [Meeting Date],
        2
    ) = 5,
    [Meeting Date] + 4,
    IF(
        WEEKDAY(
            [Meeting Date],
            2
            ) = 4, 
            [Meeting Date] + 4,
            [Meeting Date] + 2
    )
)
```

The column that I am having issues with is the `[Final Date]` combined with the use of another column `[Submitted To]` which is a yes/no column. If `[Submitted To]` is not checked, then the `[Final Date]` is equal to `[Initial Date]` column (which already skips over the weekend dates and only accounts for business days). If `[Submitted To]` is checked, then `[Final Date]` will equal `[Initial Date] + 5`. The issue is that if the `[Submitted To]` is checked, it does not account for weekends.

**[Final Date] Formula (Not accounting for weekends that works**
`=IF([Submit To PO],IF(ISBLANK([Initial Submission Due Date]),"",[Initial Submission Due Date]+5),[Initial Submission Due Date])`

I receive `The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.` when I try the below formula

Please see formula below:

```
[Final Date] Formula
=IF(
    [Submitted To],
    IF(
        ISBLANK(
            [Initial Date]
        ),
        "",
        ),
        IF(
            WEEKDAY(
            [Initial Date],
            2
            ) = 1,
            [Initial Date] + 7
            ),
        IF(
            WEEKDAY(
            [Initial Date],
            2
            ) = 2,
            [Initial Date] + 7
            ),
        IF(
            WEEKDAY(
            [Initial Date],
            2
            ) = 3,
            [Initial Date] + 7
            ),
        IF(
            WEEKDAY(
            [Initial Date],
            2
            ) = 4,
            [Initial Date] + 7
            ),
        IF(
            WEEKDAY(
            [Initial Date],
            2
            ) = 5,
            [Initial Date] + 7
            ),
    [Initial Date]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for `IF` function in calculated column formula is:

```
IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)
```

So, you have use nested IF functions true and false values in above format.

Try using formula like:

```
=IF(
    [Submitted To],
    IF(
        ISBLANK([Initial Date]),
        "",
        IF(
            WEEKDAY([Initial Date],2) = 1,
            [Initial Date] + 7,
            IF(
                WEEKDAY([Initial Date],2) = 2,
                [Initial Date] + 7,
                IF(
                    WEEKDAY([Initial Date],2) = 3,
                    [Initial Date] + 7,
                    IF(
                        WEEKDAY([Initial Date],2) = 4,
                        [Initial Date] + 7,
                        IF(
                            WEEKDAY([Initial Date],2) = 5,
                            [Initial Date] + 7,
                            [Initial Date] + 5
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    [Initial Date]
)
```

You can change `[Initial Date] + 5` parameter in above formula as per your requirements.

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`). For example: If you are using German language for your SharePoint site

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a)

Comment: Ganesh, thank you for your response. When I try this formula, I get the same invalid syntax error!

Comment: Are you using correct column names in your formula? Column names in formula are case sensitive. You have to use the correct display name of columns.

Comment: The column names are correct, I even tried typing in the formula instead of pasting it, same error

Comment: I even tried putting in NP++, and finding all/replacing all column names with the correct display name copied and pasted from SharePoint column settings. Still says invalid syntax or is not supported

Comment: There was a `,` missing before last `[Initial Date]`. I have updated the formula in answer. Can you try it now?

Comment: It works perfect!